# Read texture coordinates from .obj made by Meshroom

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm working on a openGL project.

I need to load a textured mesh in .obj format creader by [meshroom](https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom).

Meshroom generates the mesh file and also one or more texture images:

```
texture_1001.jpg
texture_1002.jpg
...
```

There is an exemple of texture file:

[image]

The .obj contains the folowing texture coordinates:

```
...
vt 0.672272 0.015525
vt 0.671467 0.012538
vt 0.670881 0.016331
vt 0.671256 0.021152
vt 1.027968 0.921876
vt 1.027573 0.923187
vt 1.026593 0.922387
...
```

I've 3 textures files and x coodinate of vt goes from 0 to 2.6. So I'm assuming the integer of the x coordinate matches the number of the texture. If I have something like:

```
vt 1.574 0.945
```

This means that this coordinates comes from the 2nd texture file (texture_1002.jpg)

By assuming this, I wrote the following small algorithm:

```
glm::vec3 tex;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float z = 0;

//Read line in .obj
fscanf_s(file, "%f %f\n", &x, &y);

z = std::round(x);
x = x - z;
            
tex.x = x;
tex.y = y;
tex.z = z;
```

But unfortunately I get a very disappointing result:

[image]

We see the borders between the different texture "patches"

Here is how I load the texures if it helps:

```
glGenTextures(1, &ID);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ID);

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGB, size, size, images.size(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
int count = 0;
for (auto path : images)
{
    int w, h, n;
    
    unsigned char* bytes = stbi_load(path, &w, &h, &n, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
        0, 0, 0, count++,
        w, h, 1,
        GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        bytes);
    stbi_image_free(bytes);
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ID);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
```

I've been tearing my hair for several hours but I can't find a solution...

Comment: use `z = std::floor(x);` instead of `z = std::round(x);` :) if you will have 1.56 it will becomes 2.0, so you will get coords like `1.56 - 2.0 = -0.44` instead of `0.56` and bad `z` value

Comment: It works much better, very stupid mistake... Thank you very much! But border are still present, I update my post

Comment: I guess the seams are coming from the interpolation between the last pixel of the first texture and the first pixel of the second texture. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to fix this (without uploading all images as one single texture). You can either perform the interpolation yourself in the shader, or you could pad all images by one additional pixel, but all of that requires special case handling in the shader.

Comment: are you sure the integer part of x is the texture? in obj files the texture file used is set by last defined material ID in `*.obj` and the mapping between materials and texture filenames is in `*.mtl` file

Comment: I've merge my three texture files in one file and I still have the seams. So I don't think that's come from the `*.mtl` file